# Nested Loop Binding in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, templating

I am making web app using Java/Spring/Thymeleaf and don't seem to be able to get past this problem!

So, here's my thymeleaf template code:

```
<form th:action="@{/holiday/create}" th:object="${holiday}" method="post">
    <select name="user_scroll">
        <option th:each="user : ${allUsers}" th:value="${user.id}"
                th:text="${user.email}" th:field="${holiday.user_id}" />
    </select>
    <button type="submit">
        Create
    </button>
</form>
```

I have read the related questions on here but am still stumped.
I did read that you can't bind an object directly that's why I am trying to bind to the user_id property of the holiday object.  I did suspect the holiday object my be out of scope but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Perhaps I am accessing the user_id property incorrectly?

When I click submit and follow debug through to my controller user_id is just sent through as null.
I hope that's enough info - let me know if I need to provide more.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact problem you have?

Answer (score 1):

Frankie, try adding the **th:field** attribute to the **select** object instead of putting it in the **option**. Like this:

```
 <select name="user_scroll" th:field="*{user_id}">
```

Notice the SPel syntax. Starts with an asterisk instead of **$** and says **user_id** instead of **holiday.user_id**. You can access the field directly this way, since you already have defined it as your selected object in the form definition using

```
th:object="${holiday}"
```

This will also bind the selected value to the user_id property of your backing object and should solve  the problem.